# Collapsed menu on navbar not appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, responsive

In my bootcamp we are making NavBars with bootstrap.  The menu is fine on a desktop viewport but when I inspect the page only the NavBar brand remains.  So far I have tried to re-arrange the  element that the  is contained within.

```
 <div class="container">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-collapse navbar-expand-sm">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> textOne</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the brand to dissappear, try putting it inside your dive with the classes  collapse and navbar-collapse.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-collapse navbar-expand-sm">
           
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> textOne</a>
               <ul class="navbar-nav">
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
        </nav>
```